# How can I get Eclipse to recognize my Nexus 7?

Tags: android, eclipse, driver, adb

This is the process I have gone through:

- I downloaded the USB driver through Eclipse.
- Then I went into the developer options on my Nexus, and I turned on USB debugging as well as the mock locations option, and then changed the debugging option to true in my main.xml.
- After this I went  and changed the connection to PTP.
- I then connected my device and allowed it to install the drivers it needed to recognize itself in device manager.
- I went into device manager and find my device listed as a camera and update the driver so that it now lists my device as an Android Composite ADB Interface.  **This is where I am having trouble.**

Even though it is listed as such in my device manager, I am still unable to discover it in Eclipse.  I think it may have something to do with the fact that **it is still being listed as a camera as well as an Android device in device manager**.

I've tried uninstalling both drivers for the device and then installing it again, but to no avail.  I've also tried resetting adb in Eclipse and in command prompt and that didn't work either.  I would try and remove the drivers for the device off my computer, but I don't know where to find them.

Can anyone give me any ideas?

Comment: try restarting adb. It might work.

Answer (score 1):

download the usb driver from http://www.asus.com/Tablets_Mobile/Nexus_7/#support_Download_32 , then install it in device manager. Dont forget to tick the "debugging mode" (in developer option).

my nexus 7 will prompt me whether want to allow to be accessed or not, just ok and all will be fined.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, so this took a while but I finally got it working.  I removed SDK from my computer with all of the installments, and then installed it again in a different location.  Somehow this worked.

Answer (score 0):

for me after i went to settings--->About Phone---> and then clicked on "Build number" at least 5 to 7 times to enable developer mode i had this issue.  Turns out i didn't realize that after enable developer options this only makes the option APPEAR IN YOUR ANDROID AS IN PREVIOUS VERSIONS.  I then went back into settings and found developer options and checked off use for debugging etc and it worked as i ran "adb devices" at command prompt and it shows up